# permission state with API23 and old version

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I set my gradle for min API 18 and Tagret API23.
I use the new permission system as need for API23 and also write all the require permission in the manifest as in the old days.
On Device use API23 it is work O.K.
But when I put the APK on device with 5.1.1 also it show me all the require permission during installation and i accept it, it is look that it doesn't get them in the application itself.
I also check in the application setting of this APK on the device and see all the permission are there (there is no checkbox so I assume if it is written it is enable).
Does the new permission system together with the old way (permission in manifest ) has to addapt automaticly to the device API level, or I need to make any check during the application runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by myself. For install the new APK I have to remove the older one  completely. If I just go to the setting->Application found the app and delete it by “remove completely” it is not enough. I have to go to the actionBar on top in the same window and by the 3 buttons ask to “remove for all users”.  Only then it doesn't have any trace and when I install the new APK it gets the right permission automatically.